# 2 Threads taking turns printing the alphabet

Tags: java, multithreading

I am supposed to write code for an assignment. The goal is to make 2 threads (which are objects of a class that implements runnable) take turns printing the alphabet. One of them prints upper case while the other one prints lower case.
(they print only a single letter each turn, not the whole alphabet, just for clarification)

I feel like my code is pretty self-explainatory but if I am wrong here and you have questions please ask them! I appreciate any help I can get for sure!

The Code:

```
public class ABCPrinter implements Runnable {

    // --- Attributes ---

   private boolean bool_isUpperCase;
   public  boolean bool_Switch = true;

   // --- Constructor ---

   public ABCPrinter (boolean init_isUpperCase) {

       this.bool_isUpperCase = init_isUpperCase;

   }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() { // custom run method

        for (char char_Counter = 'a'; char_Counter <= 'z'; char_Counter++) { // count through the alphabet

            if (bool_isUpperCase){ // decide whether to print upper or lower case

                if(bool_Switch) {

                    System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(char_Counter));
                    System.out.println("\n----------------------");
                    System.out.println("Message has been sent.");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------");

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    } catch(Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("\nInterrupted.");

                    }

                    bool_Switch = false;
                    System.out.println("\n--------------------");
                    System.out.println("Switch has been set to false.");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------");

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(10000);

                        notifyAll();
                        System.out.println("\n--------------------");
                        System.out.println("All threads have been notified.");
                        System.out.println("-----------------------");

                        Thread.sleep(10000);

                        wait();
                        System.out.println("\n--------------------");
                        System.out.println("Thread 1 is waiting.");
                        System.out.println("-----------------------");

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("Process Interrupted.");

                    }

                } else {

                    try {

                        System.out.println("Thread 1 is waiting.");
                        wait();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("Process Interrupted.");

                    }

                }

            } else {

                if(!bool_Switch) {

                    System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(char_Counter));
                    System.out.println("\n----------------------");
                    System.out.println("Message has been sent.");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------");

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    } catch(Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("\nInterrupted.");

                    }

                    bool_Switch = true;
                    System.out.println("\n--------------------");
                    System.out.println("Switch has been set to true.");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------");

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                        notifyAll();
                        System.out.println("\n--------------------");
                        System.out.println("All threads have been notified.");
                        System.out.println("-----------------------");

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                        wait();
                        System.out.println("\n--------------------");
                        System.out.println("Thread 2 is waiting.");
                        System.out.println("-----------------------");

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("Process Interrupted.");

                    }

                } else {

                    try {

                        System.out.println("Thread 2 is waiting.");
                        wait();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("Process Interrupted.");

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Here is the main method where everything is executed:

```
public class Main2 {

    public boolean bool_switch;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ABCPrinter p1 = new ABCPrinter(true);
        ABCPrinter p2 = new ABCPrinter(false);
        
        Thread thr_UpperCase = new Thread(p1);
        Thread thr_LowerCase = new Thread(p2);

        thr_UpperCase.start();
        thr_LowerCase.start();

    }

}
```

Like I said I appreciate any help or advice for improvement. I would first and foremost love to get it to work though, been stuck at this assignment for 2 days now.

Have a good one!

Comment: This site is not for general code review. This site is for specific solutions to a specific issue. Perhaps appropriate for sister site, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't aware of the existence of that website. Thanks for the heads-up, though!

Comment: FYI: Maybe your teacher didn't tell you, but you deserve to know: This exercise goes completely against the whole idea of threads. The entire _purpose_ of threads is to allow different activities in a program to happen _independently_ of each other. When a program forces threads to operate in lock-step like this, then that completely eliminates any benefit from using threads. Of course, the threads must _occasionally_ meet up with each other--otherwise, you might as well just write a bunch of single-threaded programs. But, your goal should be to minimize the number of those meet-ups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This new answer involves the usage of wait and notify as requested by you.The main function changed a little to include a mutex Object that is used for synchronization:

Main:

```
public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Mutex object that will serve as a lock
        final Object mutex = new Object();

        ABCPrinter p1 = new ABCPrinter(mutex, true);
        ABCPrinter p2 = new ABCPrinter(mutex, false);

        final Thread thr_UpperCase = new Thread(p1);
        final Thread thr_LowerCase = new Thread(p2);


        thr_LowerCase.start();
        thr_UpperCase.start();

        thr_LowerCase.join();
        thr_UpperCase.join();

    }
}
```

ABC Printer:

```
public class ABCPrinter implements Runnable {
    private final Object mutex;
    private static char currentChar;

    private final boolean printUpperCaseBoolean;

    static {
        currentChar = 'a';
    }

        public ABCPrinter(final Object mutex, final boolean printUpperCaseBoolean) {
            this.mutex = mutex;
            this.printUpperCaseBoolean = printUpperCaseBoolean;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (currentChar <= 'z') {
                if (printUpperCaseBoolean) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (mutex) {
                            System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(currentChar));
                            currentChar++;
                            mutex.wait();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                        interruptedException.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        // Wait so that this thread can't start directly again
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        synchronized (mutex) {
                            System.out.println(currentChar);
                            currentChar++;
                            mutex.notify();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This prints:
A
b
C
d
E
f
G
h
I
j
K
l
M
n
O
p
Q
r
S
t
U
v
W
x
Y
z

Comment: Thanks a lot! I struggled so hard trying to correctly implement synchronized. Actually seeing it work in the context of my issue helps a lot! 
I will go through the code in detail later, can I come back at you if I have any questions?

Comment: Sure. You can always ask.

Comment: `static {
        currentChar = 'a';
    }`


What does this static construct do exactly?
Also im not exactly sure how the code within the synchronized parts work.  i see there is no wait() in the second synchronized, doenst that mean that this thread will just continue printing?

Comment: You mentioned in your assignement that you Need top Print something like AbC, so the two threads need to be perfectly synced. That is why you need only one variable (so called class attribute). This variable can now be used and accessed by both of them.

Comment: Because Ab and not aB should be printed.  The thread printing the capitel letters needs to run first. After it prints the capital letters, it starts to wait. 
Now the thread printing the lower case characters starts it prints the char and then notifies the capitel letter printing thread to continue his work etc. Because we synchronise on the shared mutex variable. Both threads can't print at the same time or print more characters than the other one. They take turns. You can try this by adding more Thread.sleep() expressions in the thread.

Comment: It will always print the characters in the specified order, no matter how you change the execution time of a thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with concurrencies and Threads. The class Semaphore is actually pretty helpful. I used the Producer-Consumer Pattern to solve your problem.Also keep in mind to use the join function in your Main.

Main:
public class Main2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    ABCPrinter p1 = new ABCPrinter(true);
    ABCPrinter p2 = new ABCPrinter(false);

    final Thread thr_UpperCase = new Thread(p1);
    final Thread thr_LowerCase = new Thread(p2);



    thr_LowerCase.start();
    thr_UpperCase.start();

    thr_LowerCase.join();
    thr_UpperCase.join();

}
```

}

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ABCPrinter implements Runnable {
    private final boolean printUpperCaseBoolean;
    private static final Semaphore FREE_SEMAPHORE;
    private static final Semaphore WORK_SEMAPHORE;
    private static final Semaphore MUTEX_SEMAPHORE;

    static{
        FREE_SEMAPHORE = new Semaphore(0);
        WORK_SEMAPHORE = new Semaphore(1);
        MUTEX_SEMAPHORE = new Semaphore(2);
    }

    public ABCPrinter(final boolean printUpperCaseBoolean) {
        this.printUpperCaseBoolean = printUpperCaseBoolean;

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (char char_Counter = 'a'; char_Counter <= 'z'; char_Counter++) { // count through the alphabet

            if(printUpperCaseBoolean){
            try{
                WORK_SEMAPHORE.acquire();
                MUTEX_SEMAPHORE.acquire();
                System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(char_Counter));
                MUTEX_SEMAPHORE.release();
                FREE_SEMAPHORE.release();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            }else{
                try {
                    FREE_SEMAPHORE.acquire();
                    MUTEX_SEMAPHORE.acquire();
                    System.out.println(char_Counter);
                    MUTEX_SEMAPHORE.release();
                    WORK_SEMAPHORE.release();
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like:

A
a
B
b
C
c
D
d
E
e
F
f
G
g
H
h
I
i
J
j
K
k
L
l
M
m
N
n
O
o
P
p
Q
q
R
r
S
s
T
t
U
u
V
v
W
w
X
x
Y
y
Z
z

Comment: Thanks! I actually found this stuff online too but tried to figure it out on my own without it because the assignment didn't mention Semaphore. I will look into it!
How would you go about it if you wanted the output to look like this?:

A b C d E f G h I j K l M n .....

Comment: I just read the assignment again and it states that I have to use wait and notify so semaphores are not an option

Comment: Oh that sounds a little bit more complicated. I will have a look at this later.